# How to get IP / URL of an Application?

Tags: php, android, c++

I searched internet but i cant find any answer .
I want to about Android application.

Is it possible to get the IP or URL thus is used inside the app. As backend like Facebook apps might be using https://api.facebook.com , 
Whatsapp might be using https://whatsapp.net/api/v*/

I created an app and backend is e.g 192.168.137.1 , 
Is it possible for someone to know where is my app backend .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can.

1. Decompilation app and investigate code
2. See network statistics via netstat for example
3. Sniffer

Comment: Can you tell me , how can i 1- Decompilation app and inv code ??? I tried but i cant read url.java file that contains backend URL -- is thr any way to sure the app , get rid of hackers ,,

Comment: @AmjadDader you can try decompile your java-app with jadx, for example...